# To Create changeable function depend on column like Excel left double click in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

As you know, Excel have a auto fill function (double click or drag). It offer changeable reference depend on column position. ex) C1 tab =A1+B1, C2 tab =A2+B2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CJQk.png)

My question is how do i create a that function in python pandas.

For example, I have a time series dataframe. I want to create column named '5diff'. Sum r_c data last 5 market days(20170601~20170608). and second row have sum last 5 market days(2017-06-02~2017-06-09) . How do I create a code? Thank you. I can not English well. If you find wrong thing, please correct.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import csv
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


start = datetime.datetime(2017,6,1)
end = datetime.datetime(2017,7,1)
f = web.DataReader('005930', 'google', start, end)
c = f['Close']
f['r_c']=c.pct_change()
f




















                Open       High        Low      Close  Volume       r_c
Date                                                                    
2017-06-01  2243000.0  2245000.0  2220000.0  2234000.0  193891       NaN
2017-06-02  2253000.0  2298000.0  2250000.0  2298000.0  247894  0.028648
2017-06-05  2302000.0  2318000.0  2286000.0  2297000.0  150954 -0.000435
2017-06-07  2325000.0  2325000.0  2262000.0  2265000.0  243638 -0.013931
2017-06-08  2250000.0  2279000.0  2250000.0  2258000.0  274158 -0.003091
2017-06-09  2284000.0  2322000.0  2280000.0  2305000.0  227782  0.020815
2017-06-12  2271000.0  2280000.0  2257000.0  2269000.0  217181 -0.015618
2017-06-13  2257000.0  2281000.0  2257000.0  2270000.0  167722  0.000441
2017-06-14  2290000.0  2303000.0  2262000.0  2268000.0  194743 -0.000881
2017-06-15  2284000.0  2296000.0  2259000.0  2284000.0  182884  0.007055
2017-06-16  2275000.0  2297000.0  2273000.0  2279000.0  301134 -0.002189
2017-06-19  2279000.0  2328000.0  2278000.0  2328000.0  212538  0.021501
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) with [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.window.Rolling.sum.html):

```
df = df.rolling(5).sum()
print (df)
                  Open        High         Low       Close     Volume  \
Date                                                                    
2017-06-01         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN   
2017-06-02         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN   
2017-06-05         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN   
2017-06-07         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN   
2017-06-08  11373000.0  11465000.0  11268000.0  11352000.0  1110535.0   
2017-06-09  11414000.0  11542000.0  11328000.0  11423000.0  1144426.0   
2017-06-12  11432000.0  11524000.0  11335000.0  11394000.0  1113713.0   
2017-06-13  11387000.0  11487000.0  11306000.0  11367000.0  1130481.0   
2017-06-14  11352000.0  11465000.0  11306000.0  11370000.0  1081586.0   
2017-06-15  11386000.0  11482000.0  11315000.0  11396000.0   990312.0   
2017-06-16  11377000.0  11457000.0  11308000.0  11370000.0  1063664.0   
2017-06-19  11385000.0  11505000.0  11329000.0  11429000.0  1059021.0   

                 r_c  
Date                  
2017-06-01       NaN  
2017-06-02       NaN  
2017-06-05       NaN  
2017-06-07       NaN  
2017-06-08       NaN  
2017-06-09  0.032006  
2017-06-12 -0.012260  
2017-06-13 -0.011384  
2017-06-14  0.001666  
2017-06-15  0.011812  
2017-06-16 -0.011192  
2017-06-19  0.025927
```

and if necessary [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) data:

```
df = df.rolling(5).sum().shift(-5)
print (df)
                  Open        High         Low       Close     Volume  \
Date                                                                    
2017-06-01  11414000.0  11542000.0  11328000.0  11423000.0  1144426.0   
2017-06-02  11432000.0  11524000.0  11335000.0  11394000.0  1113713.0   
2017-06-05  11387000.0  11487000.0  11306000.0  11367000.0  1130481.0   
2017-06-07  11352000.0  11465000.0  11306000.0  11370000.0  1081586.0   
2017-06-08  11386000.0  11482000.0  11315000.0  11396000.0   990312.0   
2017-06-09  11377000.0  11457000.0  11308000.0  11370000.0  1063664.0   
2017-06-12  11385000.0  11505000.0  11329000.0  11429000.0  1059021.0   
2017-06-13         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN   
2017-06-14         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN   
2017-06-15         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN   
2017-06-16         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN   
2017-06-19         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN   

                 r_c  
Date                  
2017-06-01  0.032006  
2017-06-02 -0.012260  
2017-06-05 -0.011384  
2017-06-07  0.001666  
2017-06-08  0.011812  
2017-06-09 -0.011192  
2017-06-12  0.025927  
2017-06-13       NaN  
2017-06-14       NaN  
2017-06-15       NaN  
2017-06-16       NaN  
2017-06-19       NaN
```

And if need difference by [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html):

```
df = df.rolling(5).sum().diff().shift(-5)
print (df)
               Open     High      Low    Close   Volume       r_c
Date                                                             
2017-06-01  41000.0  77000.0  60000.0  71000.0  33891.0       NaN
2017-06-02  18000.0 -18000.0   7000.0 -29000.0 -30713.0 -0.044266
2017-06-05 -45000.0 -37000.0 -29000.0 -27000.0  16768.0  0.000876
2017-06-07 -35000.0 -22000.0      0.0   3000.0 -48895.0  0.013050
2017-06-08  34000.0  17000.0   9000.0  26000.0 -91274.0  0.010146
2017-06-09  -9000.0 -25000.0  -7000.0 -26000.0  73352.0 -0.023004
2017-06-12   8000.0  48000.0  21000.0  59000.0  -4643.0  0.037119
2017-06-13      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN       NaN
2017-06-14      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN       NaN
2017-06-15      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN       NaN
2017-06-16      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN       NaN
2017-06-19      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN       NaN
```